# Unable to execute else statements in onPostExecute() method of AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

EditText uEmail, uPassword;
String emailID, password;
CheckBox chkRememberMe;
JSONObject jsonResponseObject, jsonObject, data;
String url = "";
String jsonResponseString = "";
String accessToken;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
String urlString = " http://192.168.2.17:8000/api/v1/login/?format=json";
Boolean error, success;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    uEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtEmailId);
    uPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);
    chkRememberMe = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkRememberMe);
    }


public void signUp(View v) {
    startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class));
}

public void login(View v) {
    Log.e("Login", "clicked");
    emailID = uEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    password = uPassword.getText().toString().trim();
    new LoginTask().execute(emailID, password);

}

class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        emailID = params[0];
        Log.e("email", emailID);
        password = params[1];
        Log.e("Password", password);
        // convert text data to JSON format
        jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject.accumulate("email", emailID);
            jsonObject.accumulate("password", password);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("Parsing error", ex.toString());
        }

        //convert json data to String which have to send
        String jsonStringToPost = jsonObject.toString();
        Log.e("JSON String to post", jsonStringToPost);

        try {
            //sending data to API
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            //urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(15000); //Sets the maximum time to wait for an input stream read to complete before giving up
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000); //Sets the maximum time in milliseconds to wait while connecting
            OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            out.write(jsonStringToPost);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            //getting response
            InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String responseData = br.readLine();
            while (responseData != null) {
                sb.append(responseData);
                responseData = br.readLine();
            }
            br.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("Connection error", ex.toString());
        }
        jsonResponseString = sb.toString();
        return jsonResponseString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        jsonResponseString = s;
        Log.e("Response String", jsonResponseString);
        try {
            jsonResponseObject = new JSONObject(jsonResponseString);

            if (success = jsonResponseObject.getBoolean("success")) {
                Log.e("Success", String.valueOf(success));
            } else if(error = jsonResponseObject.getBoolean("error")) {
                Log.e("Error", String.valueOf(error));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is the code of my Login Page. On clicking login button, `login()` method is called.I am sending `emailId` and `password` in `JSON` format to API through `AsyncTask`. In the `onPostExecute()`, I am using `JSON` response string received from API. I will get `success = true` for successful login and `error = true` for invalid login.

Inside the `onPostExecute()` method, I want to check whether login was successful or unsuccessful using `if-else` condition but I am not able to execute else part even after providing invalid `emailID` and `password`. Can't we use `if-else` in `onPostExecute()` method?

**JSON on successful login**

```
{ 
    "data": 
        { 
            "access_token": "2c1KjajSYDS6kJqzD1wJ1eGZTO2JbC", 
            "token_type": 
            "Bearer", 
            "expires_in": 36000, 
            "refresh_token": "HLYN8H38G2f9wR8doPxKBNDCZ7KFMg", 
            "scope": "read write groups" 
        }, 
    "success": true 
}
```

**JSON on unsuccessful login**

```
{ 
    "data": "User not found, kindly check your username and password and try again.", 
    "error": true 
}
```

Comment: firstly, you are assigning `=` not comparing `==`. you need to use `==` or `.equals()` method. and why are you using `getboolean()` ? what does your json response look like

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but maybe the `if` assignment is always evaluated to true because the assign is legal, and therefore you won't get to the else part?

Try to use:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    jsonResponseString = s;
    Log.e("Response String", jsonResponseString);
    try {
        jsonResponseObject = new JSONObject(jsonResponseString);

        if (jsonResponseObject.getBoolean("success")) {
            success = jsonResponseObject.getBoolean("success");
            Log.e("Success", String.valueOf(success));
        } else if(jsonResponseObject.getBoolean("error")) {
            error = jsonResponseObject.getBoolean("error");
            Log.e("Error", String.valueOf(error));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: ,i have done exactly the same thing,But still its not working.

Comment: On successful login,i get {
    "data": {
        "access_token": "2c1KjajSYDS6kJqzD1wJ1eGZTO2JbC",
        "token_type": "Bearer",
        "expires_in": 36000,
        "refresh_token": "HLYN8H38G2f9wR8doPxKBNDCZ7KFMg",
        "scope": "read write groups"
    },
    "success": true
}                                                                                                            On unsuccessful login:    {
    "data": "User not found, kindly check your username and password and try again.",
    "error": true
}

Comment: OK, and when running with the debugger, what is happening inside the function?

Comment: I don't know how to use debugger.

Comment: hmm, tough one. ok, so let's go old-school. try to print the json to the log and when run this code section, look at the log and check what is the json you actually got, and maybe we'll find the root cause of the problem.

Comment: JSON which i got on successful login and unsuccessful login is what i have sent to u after validating it on JSONlint.There is no problem with JSON string.I am getting the correct JSON string in Log .

Comment: Try add to the onPostExecute function:

`Log.d("DEBUG onPostExecute", "json " + jsonResponseObject.getBoolean("success"));`

And try to do successful login, and then show me the output for this debug line

Comment: D/DEBUG onPostExecute﹕ json true

Comment: ok, so you actually get the boolean "true" value for successful login.
Now, how you can tell that the if statement does not work for you?

Comment: Both the conditions are working individually but when i am using if-else construct or two different if conditions for succesfull and unsuccessful login,only first will get executed.This is the issue.

Comment: I just noticed that i forgot to add ";" after my assignments.
Try to use my suggested code now please.

Generally, it should work. I have no idea what else interrupts it.

Comment: Got the solution, i have to use the following code to fix the issue:                 if (jsonResponseObject.has("success) {
            success = jsonResponseObject.getBoolean("success");
            Log.e("Success", String.valueOf(success));
        } else if(jsonResponseObject.has("error")) {
            error = jsonResponseObject.getBoolean("error");
            Log.e("Error", String.valueOf(error));
        }

Answer (score 0):

as Karan Mer has said, you have put wrong code there.
If you have to compare you should use "==", not the assignment operator"=".
Also you are comparing the response with "success" and "error" booleans but you haven't initialized them so value of both of them would always be false.
Better you just check success value from the response, that's enough...
Replace your code with,

```
if (jsonResponseObject.has("success")) {
    success = jsonResponseObject.getBoolean("success");
    Log.e("Success", String.valueOf(success));
} else if(jsonResponseObject.has("error")){
    error = jsonResponseObject.getBoolean("error");
    Log.e("Error", String.valueOf(error));
}
```

This will make sure if it has the boolean "success" then only it will check for it. Ideally in this case the response should have only "success" value as true or false and it doesn't need the "error" boolean anymore.

Comment: ,this is what i am discussing with Avihoo.

Comment: have you replaced your code with mine or Avihoo's and then run?

Comment: Try to log these values when you store them in "success" and "error" variables, Log.v("value of my success var : ", ""+success);  and Log.v("value of my error var : ", ""+error);

Comment: Here the actual problem is that if jsonResponseObject is not getting success string ,it is not executing the else part.I guess it throws some sort of exception when it is not finding its string.I am not sure.